# CKEditor Stylesheet Parser

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am working with CKEditor 4.4.5 and its plugin Stylesheet Parser 4.4, but I get empty list from the style drop-down.

To make my question easier to understand, please try this code (download from its example site: http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/styles.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <title>Stylesheet Parser plugin</title>
    <script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.2/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <textarea cols="80" id="editor2" name="editor2" rows="10" >&lt;p&gt;This is some &lt;strong&gt;sample text&lt;/strong&gt;. You are using &lt;a href="http://ckeditor.com/"&gt;CKEditor&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;
    </textarea>

    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2', {
            extraPlugins: 'stylesheetparser',
            height: 300,

            // Custom stylesheet for editor content.
            contentsCss: [ 'http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/assets/stylesheetparser/stylesheetparser.css' ],

            // Do not load the default Styles configuration.
            stylesSet: []

        } );
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It doesn't really work. But the sample on that site works well.
I also find another sample site:
http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor_4.3_beta/samples/plugins/stylesheetparser/stylesheetparser.html

I tried to copy all the sources code from this demo site, but get no luck.

Did anyone else have the same problem?
How can I make the codes above work? It basically uses the source codes from CDN site so I don't think the version of source code matters.

Comment: cross-domain request? You're pulling the .js code from cdn.ckeditor.com, but trying to load the css from sdk.ckeditor.com. check your JS request for errors/warnings, in any case.

Comment: No errors in the console. Loading the css from sdk.ckeditor.com is fine because I think the site owner set it to allow cross-domain request. Also, I have tried with my local CSS file. Same results: empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by Cross-domain request. The CSS file is in HTTP server, and my application is running with a port number. So they are treated as cross domain request.

I also tested the HTML page and CSS file in the local files. However, file://...path is still treated as Cross Domain request in Chrome, but FF and IE works with that properly though.

When I tried this in server, it works properly with Chrome. Unfortunately, there seems no way to make cross domain request work in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with this version: http://ckeditor.com/addon/stylesheetparser-fixed 
The official plugin has some problems since very long ago but they don't seem to plan to fix them.

Comment: But are you testing with a cross-domain stylesheet? I don't think that would work, I only suggested this plugin because it helps in normal setups when there's issues with the cache and the timing to load the stylesheets

Comment: I think I found the problem. I used a local css file now. It works fine in IE and FireFox, but it doesn't work in Chrome. The problem is that in the function LoadStylesCSS( theDoc, skipSelectors, validSelectors ). theDoc.styleSheets[i].cssRules is always null in Chrome. Do you have the same problem in Chrome? @AlfonsoML

Comment: No, I don't have any problem with Chrome. Maybe it's due to some extension that you've installed?